# Перенаправление - рационально ли?

Tags: php

Вопрос о целесообразности. Решая проблему обнуления пост-данных при передаче формы и запрета на повторную передачу этой формы при обновлении страницы (и нажатии кнопок "вперед" и "назад"), применял разные хитрости. И вот сделал так(MVC). В модели, которая обрабатывает форму поместил

```
header("location: {$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}");
```

Красота! Все проблемы решены. Все очищено и обнулено, не нужно помещать скрытые поля в форму со случайными числами и т.д.
Вопрос в том, рациональное ли это решение? Страница, получается, перегружается дважды - при отправке формы и при вызове header('location').

UPDATE. К тому же не противоречит ли это философии MVC, когда из модели, вместо передачи данных ВНЕЗАПНО перезагрузка?

Comment: думаю по ресурсоёмкости это самое простое.

Comment: Во многих случаях, это единственный способ. Хотя, я эту проблему уже давно решил с помощью ajax. Просто не вижу смысла кидать юзверя то на одну, то на другую страницу.

Comment: @Deonis, дык на одну и туже страницу. Не спорю - ajax это круто.

Comment: Замечал у многих одну забавную ошибку - после установки переадресации продолжают выполнение скрипта. А ведь это одна из немногих ситуаций, где уместно `die()`... )

Comment: @Равнодушный, все ок. Один раз обжегся, теперь всегда die ...